Ionic Framework Requires a Framework
Did Ionic Framework remove the possibility to start without any framework?
>ionic start MyAPP blank

Pick a framework!

Please select the JavaScript framework to use for your new app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply a value for the
--type option.

? Framework: (Use arrow keys)
> Angular | https://angular.io
  React   | https://reactjs.org
  Vue     | https://vuejs.org

Even in the docs there is no path to follow without one of these:

What to do in this case?

Yes, Its possible to create ionic project without angular or vue or react by manually.

Adding compiled source code ionic file in html script (ionic.bundle.css, ionic.js)

Below is index.html file:
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Ionic Project</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
        <style>
            .bg-light {
                --background: lightskyblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <ion-app>
            <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar class="bg-light">
                    <ion-title>Ionic Project</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>
            <ion-content>
                <ion-button id="my-button">Click Me</ion-button>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-app>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>

Below is main.js flie
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const button = document.getElementById('my-button');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('Button clicked!');
  });
});


After adding of index.html and main.js install http-server globally
npm install -g http-server

Run server by using of below command:
http-server


Reference link for above code
Additional also refer this link for Capacitor with VanillaJS project without using angular or vue or react
